# Are these RV gamma distributed?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_i$ are independent, identically distributed exponential random variables with mean $1$. My assertion is that $iX_i\sim \text{Gamma}\,\left(1,i\right)$, however, a friend of mine told me that this is not true since $iX_i$ are not independent, ex: $2X_2=X_2+X_2$ and thus my statement does not hold (since they have to be independent). Who is right?

Comment: It will be Gamma(1,i) and you can prove it via an MGF. You can check whether you used the independence assumption or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the exponential and gamma distributions are parametrized by scale, i.e. $$X_i \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\theta), \quad \operatorname{E}[X_i] = \theta, \\ f_{X_i}(x) = \frac{1}{\theta} e^{-x/\theta}, \quad x > 0, \quad \theta > 0,$$ and $Y = iX_i$, then $$f_Y(y) = f_{X_i}(y/i) \cdot \frac{1}{i} = \frac{1}{i\theta}e^{-y/(i\theta)},$$ hence $$Y \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(1, i\theta) \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(i\theta).$$  If the distributions are parametrized by **rate** $\lambda = 1/\theta$, so $f_{X_i}(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, then $iX_i$ is gamma with rate $\lambda/i$.

Note that there is a misconception in your question.  The random variable $iX_i$ has only one $X$.  It is simply a scaled exponential distribution, which is again exponential.  So for instance, when $i = 2$ and $\theta = 1$, $2X_2$ is exponential with mean $2$.

What would happen if you added iid exponential random variables is that you would get a gamma distribution with **shape** equal to the number of such variables in the sum; i.e. $$Y = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n, \\ Y \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n , \theta), \\ f_Y(y) = \frac{y^{n-1} e^{-y/\theta}}{\theta^n \Gamma(n)}, \quad y > 0, \quad \theta > 0.$$